# Each Child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - but I have one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error "each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop" error, but I'm confused because I'm attempting to set the key to a unique ID, and it seems like it's not working.
I'm using the imdbID as the key, which should be a primary key value (unique and stable). Is my syntax wrong, or what am I doing that's incorrect here ?

```
import React from 'react';
import "./movie.css";

class Movie extends React.Component {
   render() {
       const {Title, Poster, Year, imdbID} = this.props;

       return (
           <div className="movie" key={imdbID} id={imdbID}>
               <div className="title-year">
                   <h1 className="title">{Title}</h1>
                   <h2 className="year">{Year}</h2>
               </div>
               <div className="poster">
                   <img src={Poster} alt="my movie poster"/>
               </div>
           </div>
       )
   }
}

export default Movie;
```

And here is the code that's inserting <Movie...> into the application (app.js):

```
 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
         <Search handleSendRequest={this.sendRequest}/>
         <div className="response">
          {
          this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
            return <Movie {...movie}/>
          })
          : null
          }
          
        </div>
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Apply key the <Movie  /> component, where you are mapping this.state.movies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `key` attribute to your **Movie** tags and set a unique value. As below

```
{
  this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
      return <Movie key={movie.imdbID} { ...movie
      }
      />
    }) :
    null
}
```

Comment: I don't know movies properties, So I used `index`. Ty for your comment. @Adam

Comment: Modified. @Adam

Comment: I made this update, but I'm still getting the warning. 
          {
          this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
            return <Movie key={movie.imddID} {...movie}/>
          })
          : null
          }

Comment: Nevermind--posting the code here made me see I had a typo on imddID, which should be imdbID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the key on `<Movie/>` itself:

```
      {
      this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
        return <Movie key="HERE" {...movie}/>
      })
      : null
      }
```

In particular, you need a key every time you iterate over an object. In this case you are iterating over `this.state.movies`.

You do not need the key inside Movie's render function, where you placed it, because you are not iterating over any object at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The 'key' prop should be inserted at the `<Movie/>` component, not in the div inside it.